# How to add field dynamically in loopback js?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

My frontend query :

http://localhost:8888/api/employees?access_token=adsafsaf&filter={%22where%22:{%22emp_code%22:%22EMPT01%22}}

**original where query : {"where":{"emp_code":"EMPT01"}}**

I am trying to add **"code"** field in in above incoming request dynamically.

```
Employee.observe('access', function (ctx, next) {
      // first way, it is not adding "orgId" field. 
      ctx.query.where = {
           orgId: ctx.options.data.orgId
      };
      // second way, it is not adding "orgId" field.
      const query = {};
      query['orgId'] = ctx.options.data.orgId;
      ctx.query.where = query;
      next();
  });
```

Please someone guide me, where is the wrong ?

Loopback version : 3

Thanks

Comment: Where is `ctx.options.data` coming from in a get request? I've tested your code without it and it's working.  Also you're not adding to the query, you're replacing it.

Comment: ctx.options.data : it is coming from middleware.

Comment: Try posting your connector debug string. https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Setting-debug-strings.html

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by this way.

```
Employee.observe('access', function (ctx, next) {
        // instead single , check both condition 
        if(ctx.query.where !=undefined){
            // if the request does not contain **where** then add it & filter it
            ctx.query.where.orgId = ctx.options.data.orgId;
        }else{
             ctx.query.where = {
                 orgId: ctx.options.data.orgId
             };
        }
        next();
  });
```